# Interaction between Dynamically loaded component and existing component(Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a working stackblitz. My changes are in service-based folder

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-example-1rvd1p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice-based%2Fexample.component.ts

I am trying to elaborate

Working

1) The directives and drag and drop feature work when templates statically 
    placed.

Not working

2) When I load a dynamic component(passing html content[received from a backend 
   response in real world] from Example Component to Happy Component) custom 
   directives are not working and function present in Example component is also
   not triggered from Happy Component

The data I receive from backend which I need to pass from Example 
 Component to the Happy Component

```
"<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" _ngcontent-c18="" appdropzone=""
appmovablearea="" class="dropzone">

<div _ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable=""
class="box draggable movable ng-star-inserted" touch-action="none" 
style="transform: translateX(136.8px) translateY(112.8px);"> room1 </div>

<div _ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable=""
class="box draggable movable ng-star-inserted" touch-action="none" 
style="transform: translateX(136.8px) translateY(112.8px);"> room2 </div>

</div>"
```

Comment: Can you post the static example as well and also clean up the code? I think that's partly why it's down voted. It's very difficult to understand what is going on with so much unnecessary code.

Comment: @christo8989 I have removed the component based folder and tried my best to clean up unwanted code. I have placed 5 directive files, 1 services file for drag and drop feature reason being used in the template being loaded from Example & Happy component.  (cont.)

Comment: @christo8989 And Happy component has the kind of html template I would be receiving from backend (lets say in Example compponent) and that I need to pass it to Happy Component (For now I have placed directly inside Happy component because I am not able to figure out the correct way to pass the template and last but not the least the directives(drag and drop) are not getting applied on the elements present in Happy component. Hope now I might be able to explain. Thanks!

Comment: @christo8989 The updated stackblitz link =  https://stackblitz.com/edit/save-qkcend

Comment: I think I would literally have to rewrite your code for you which is not what this is for. So I don't have an answer to solve your problem. However, I can't point you towards some solutions. 

You might want to look up state management. This will make tracking the boxes much easier between components. I recommend ngxs but you can also use ngrx or akita. Part of the reason the code is working is because the state/objects exist on that component but not on the other component.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @christo8989  I can keep on improving the code upon your suggestions , first if you could help me with how can I call functions present in Example component from Happy component as it would be dynamically loaded and suggestions on how can I make the directives work, after I reach to a proper solution u can give an answer :) and I'll accept  and one more request can the states be managed in the Example component itself becoz for only this purpose using ngx would be an overhead dont you think. Thanks alot

Comment: @christo8989 only 1 line answers(links anything) if u can give I'll implement it, (1) Passing template from Example to Happy (2) Calling functions present in Example from Happy (3) To make directives work present in Happy Component

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is how you are handling state. When you say the code works, it's because your state only exists within that one component.

So, how do you share state between two components. Poor man's state management.

**box.state.ts**

```
export interface BoxState {
  boxes: string[];
  selectedBox: string | null;
  boxesInBucket: string[];
}
```

**box.service.ts**

```
public state = new BehaviorSubject<BoxState>()

set(newState: Partial<BoxState>): void {
  this.state.next({...this.state.value, ...newState})
}
```

**any.component.ts**

```
export class AnyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sink = new SubSink();


  constructor(private boxService: BoxService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sink.add(
      this.boxService.state.subscribe(state => {
        //.. grab relevant state
      });
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sink.unsubscribe();
  }


  click(): void {
    this.boxService.set({ /* ... update state */})
  }
}
```

Checkout npm's [subsink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subsink).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris, I'll definitely incorporate this approach , but first I should be passing the template from Example to Happy , after passing the template and making the directives working , I can apply this state management